# Spring Reactive MongoDB connected to MongoDB cloud

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I downloaded the example from [Spring Data MongoDB 2.0 - Reactive examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/mongodb/reactive).

I'm failing to understand how to make it work.

---

I set up a cluster in [cloud.mongodb.com](http://cloud.mongodb.com) and they supply me with:

If I am using driver 3.6 or later:

```
mongodb+srv://stavalfi:<PASSWORD>@cluster0-9yjy8.mongodb.net/test
```

Else, if I am using driver 3.4 or earlier:

```
mongodb://stavalfi:<PASSWORD>@cluster0-shard-00-00-
9yjy8.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-
9yjy8.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-
9yjy8.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-
0&authSource=admin
```

I don't know what is the version of the driver which spring uses so I chose the first one:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
@AutoConfigureAfter(EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class ApplicationConfiguration extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration {

    private final Environment environment;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext run = SpringApplication.run(ApplicationConfiguration.class);
        run.getBean(ReactiveMongoTemplate.class)
                .save("something to push")
                .subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace, () -> System.out.println("success"));

        Thread.sleep(1000000);
    }

    @Bean
    public LoggingEventListener mongoEventListener() {
        return new LoggingEventListener();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    @DependsOn("embeddedMongoServer")
    public MongoClient reactiveMongoClient() {
        return MongoClients.create(String.format("mongodb+srv://stavalfi:<MyAccountPassword!>@cluster0-9yjy8.mongodb.net/test"));
//      int port = environment.getProperty("local.mongo.port", Integer.class);
//      return MongoClients.create(String.format("mongodb://localhost:%d", port));
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "reactive";
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm not doing anything as Spring Data MongoDB project expected me to do.

The Exception I get while creating the `Bean`: `MongoClient`

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reactiveMongoClient' defined in example.springdata.mongodb.people.ApplicationConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'reactiveMongoClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No SSL support in java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel. For SSL support use com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStreamFactoryFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at example.springdata.mongodb.people.ApplicationConfiguration.main(ApplicationConfiguration.java:53) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'reactiveMongoClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No SSL support in java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel. For SSL support use com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStreamFactoryFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No SSL support in java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel. For SSL support use com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStreamFactoryFactory
    at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStreamFactory.<init>(AsynchronousSocketChannelStreamFactory.java:58) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStreamFactory.<init>(AsynchronousSocketChannelStreamFactory.java:43) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClients.getStreamFactory(MongoClients.java:237) ~[mongodb-driver-async-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:181) ~[mongodb-driver-async-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:172) ~[mongodb-driver-async-3.6.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:90) ~[mongodb-driver-reactivestreams-1.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:75) ~[mongodb-driver-reactivestreams-1.7.1.jar:na]
    at example.springdata.mongodb.people.ApplicationConfiguration.reactiveMongoClient(ApplicationConfiguration.java:70) [classes/:na]
    at example.springdata.mongodb.people.ApplicationConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6152c801.CGLIB$reactiveMongoClient$1(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at example.springdata.mongodb.people.ApplicationConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6152c801$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4cbf5891.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at example.springdata.mongodb.people.ApplicationConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6152c801.reactiveMongoClient(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

---

How can I fix this?

Comment: `For SSL support use com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStreamFactoryFactory`...

Comment: I couldn't find any __complete__ example on `how`. Can you provide a simple example for using it inside `spring-boot-2`?

Answer (score 1):

Played around with this some. You can find details from [Mongo Java Driver tutorials](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/driver-async/tutorials/ssl/#tls-ssl).

---

First I tried using the DSL approach, which would be neat to have all the setup as code:

**application.yml**

```
mongo:
  user: training_mongo
  password: <my_password>
  hosts:
    - training-abcde.mongodb.net
  database: training
```

**MongoProperties.java**

```
@ConfigurationProperties("mongo")
@Component
public class MongoProperties {
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private List<String> hosts;
    private String database;
```

**ApplicationConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
public class ApplicationConfig extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration {

[...]

    @Override
    public MongoClient reactiveMongoClient() {
        return create(MongoClientSettings.builder()
                                         .clusterSettings(ClusterSettings.builder()
                                                                         .hosts(mongoProperties.getHosts()
                                                                                               .stream()
                                                                                               .map(ServerAddress::new)
                                                                                               .collect(toList()))
                                                                         .build())
                                         .streamFactoryFactory(NettyStreamFactory::new)
                                         .sslSettings(SslSettings.builder()
                                                                 .enabled(true)
                                                                 .build())
                                         .credential(MongoCredential.createCredential(
                                                 mongoProperties.getUser(),
                                                 mongoProperties.getDatabase(),
                                                 mongoProperties.getPassword().toCharArray()))
                                         .build());

    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return DB_NAME;
    }
```

This however crashes, because Netty fires a DNS lookup through the Java stack and that fails:

> [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     2018-08-06 17:22:17.147  INFO 16148 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
>   *[ ... stacktrace ...]*
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     2018-08-06 17:22:17.278  INFO 16148 --- [    Test worker] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[training-abcde.mongodb.net:27017], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     2018-08-06 17:22:17.279  INFO 16148 --- [    Test worker] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server training-abcde.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     2018-08-06 17:22:17.975  INFO 16148 --- [    Test worker] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
>   [TestEventLogger]     2018-08-06 17:22:18.006  INFO 16148 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server training-abcde.mongodb.net:27017
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
>   *[...  stacktrace ...]*
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     **Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known (training-abcde.mongodb.net)**
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]          at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:na]
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]          at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:925) ~[na:na]
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]          at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1505) ~[na:na]
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]          at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:844) ~[na:na]
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]          at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1495) ~[na:na]
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]          at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1354) ~[na:na]
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]          at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1288) ~[na:na]
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]          at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1238) ~[na:na]
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]          at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:146) ~[netty-common-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]          at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:143) ~[netty-common-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]          at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]

---

But doing things less elegantly via the connection URL seem to work:

**ApplicationConfiguration.java**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
public class ApplicationConfig extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration {

    private static final String CONNECTION_URL = "mongodb+srv://%s:%s@%s/%s?retryWrites=true&streamType=netty&ssl=true";

    [...]

    @Override
    public MongoClient reactiveMongoClient() {
        return MongoClients.create(getMongoConnectionUrl());
    }


    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return DB_NAME;
    }

    private String getMongoConnectionUrl() {
        String connectionUrl = String.format(CONNECTION_URL, mongoProperties.getUser(), mongoProperties.getPassword(),
                                             mongoProperties.getHosts().get(0), mongoProperties.getDatabase());

        return connectionUrl;
    }
```

> [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     2018-08-06 18:25:37.132  INFO 4252 --- [    Test worker] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[training-shard-00-00-abcde.mongodb.net:27017, training-shard-00-01-abcde.mongodb.net:27017, training-shard-00-02-abcde.mongodb.net:27017], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=REPLICA_SET, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500, requiredReplicaSetName='training-shard-0'}
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     2018-08-06 18:25:37.132  INFO 4252 --- [    Test worker] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server training-shard-00-00-abcde.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     2018-08-06 18:25:37.135  INFO 4252 --- [    Test worker] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server training-shard-00-01-abcde.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     2018-08-06 18:25:37.139  INFO 4252 --- [    Test worker] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server training-shard-00-02-abcde.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     2018-08-06 18:25:37.831  INFO 4252 --- [    Test worker] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     2018-08-06 18:25:38.450  INFO 4252 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:161155}] to training-shard-00-00-abcde.mongodb.net:27017
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     2018-08-06 18:25:38.468  INFO 4252 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=training-shard-00-00-abcde.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 6, 6]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=16287599, setName='training-shard-0', canonicalAddress=training-shard-00-00-abcde.mongodb.net:27017, hosts=[training-shard-00-00-abcde.mongodb.net:27017, training-shard-00-02-abcde.mongodb.net:27017, training-shard-00-01-abcde.mongodb.net:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='training-shard-00-00-abcde.mongodb.net:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=7fffffff0000000000000008, setVersion=1, lastWriteDate=Mon Aug 06 18:25:37 SRET 2018, lastUpdateTimeNanos=70366873909383}
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     2018-08-06 18:25:38.473  INFO 4252 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Setting max election id to 7fffffff0000000000000008 from replica set primary training-shard-00-00-abcde.mongodb.net:27017
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     2018-08-06 18:25:38.474  INFO 4252 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Setting max set version to 1 from replica set primary training-shard-00-00-abcde.mongodb.net:27017
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     2018-08-06 18:25:38.475  INFO 4252 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Discovered replica set primary training-shard-00-00-abcde.mongodb.net:27017
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     2018-08-06 18:25:38.479  INFO 4252 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:71172}] to training-shard-00-02-abcde.mongodb.net:27017
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     2018-08-06 18:25:38.496  INFO 4252 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=training-shard-00-02-abcde.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 6, 6]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=16406907, setName='training-shard-0', canonicalAddress=training-shard-00-02-abcde.mongodb.net:27017, hosts=[training-shard-00-00-abcde.mongodb.net:27017, training-shard-00-02-abcde.mongodb.net:27017, training-shard-00-01-abcde.mongodb.net:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='training-shard-00-00-abcde.mongodb.net:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=1, lastWriteDate=Mon Aug 06 18:25:37 SRET 2018, lastUpdateTimeNanos=70366902099001}
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     2018-08-06 18:25:38.497  INFO 4252 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:224436}] to training-shard-00-01-abcde.mongodb.net:27017
>   [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     2018-08-06 18:25:38.512  INFO 4252 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=training-shard-00-01-abcde.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 6, 6]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=14614118, setName='training-shard-0', canonicalAddress=training-shard-00-01-abcde.mongodb.net:27017, hosts=[training-shard-00-00-abcde.mongodb.net:27017, training-shard-00-02-abcde.mongodb.net:27017, training-shard-00-01-abcde.mongodb.net:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='training-shard-00-00-abcde.mongodb.net:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=1, lastWriteDate=Mon Aug 06 18:25:37 SRET 2018, lastUpdateTimeNanos=70366918148773}

Answer (score 0):

I think it haven't `SSL Certificate` or may be the wrong or dummy `SSL Certificate` are there. That's why it's display `No SSL support in java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel`

Comment: Any idea how to make it work? Or it out of my hands? Also, Where is `there` (`wrong or dummy SSL Certificate are there`)?

Comment: Can you retry with 2nd, ( using driver 3.4 or earlier)

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> If you are using the reactive driver, Netty is required for SSL. The auto-configuration configures this factory automatically if Netty is available and the factory to use hasn’t been customized already.

Make sure that you have netty on the classpath (either selected modules or `netty-all`).